# What does "lawlessness" refer to in 1 John 3:4?

Tags: 1-john, law

In [1 John 3:4](http://esv.to/1John3.4) (ESV), we read:

> Everyone who makes a practice of sinning also practices lawlessness; sin is lawlessness.

My understanding is that in the LXX, the Greek word ἀνομία usually refers to the breaking the law of Moses. But in the epistle here, John doesn't really seem much concerned about the Mosaic Law. So what does he mean, then, by "sin is lawlessness"?

Answer (score 3):

νόμος in Paul is almost always Mosaic Law (though probably not in Romans 7 when he finds within himself a "law").

However, not all authors use the same words the same way. Even from above we can see that authors don't even use the same word the same way, though they may exhibit patterns.

So, to hold John up to the requirement of using νόμος to refer to Mosaic Law may lead to some confusing conclusions.

I'd venture to say that John is referring to principles. A sinful life is a life that is unprincipled ... undisciplined. It is a life that is unattached to Christ, it does not abide within him (to go back to John 15).

edit - even more:

So looking at 1 John 2 we see that John is reaffirming an old law (probably not the Mosaic Law) but that he is also writing them a new commandment, or law. This new law is linked to love through being children of the light. John is also the recorder of the new "command" to "love one another."

With this in mind, lawlessness here means to not be a child of the light, which has many horizontal and vertical implications.

Comment: Holiness is revealed to us through separation, law, judgement, etc.  Lawlessness is the opposite of Holiness.  The light, as you mention, represents holiness.  He said to us "Be ye therefore Holy."

Answer (score 1):

Some things to consider.... Lawlessness in the bible is also translated as transgressors, godless, without law, offense, wickedness, evildoers, guilty...

John 12:49 For I have NOT SPOKEN on My own, but the Father  Himself who sent Me has given Me a command as to what I should say and what I should speak.

Deuteronomy 18:18 I will raise up for them a PROPHET LIKE you from among their brothers. I will PUT MY WORDS in his mouth, and he will tell them everything I command him.

Matthew 24:12 And because LAWLESSNESS will be increased, the love of many will grow cold.

Matthew 28:20 ...teaching them to OBSERVE EVERYTHING I have commanded you. And remember,    I am with you always,    to the end of the age.”

Psalm 19:7-9 The LAW of Yahweh is perfect, reviving the soul; the testimony of Yahweh is sure, making wise the simple;   the precepts of Yahweh are right, rejoicing the heart; the commandment of Yahweh is pure, enlightening the eyes;  the fear of Yahweh is clean, enduring forever; the rules of Yahweh are true, and righteous altogether.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange! Please be sure to take our [site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about us. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In looking at this we should first establish, in my estimation, a nature of our Creator.  Here we look at his un-changeableness, (is that a word?).

In Psalm 89:34, "My covenant will I not break, nor alter the things which have gone out of My lips."

Secondly, Malachi 3:6, “For I am the Lord, I change not. Therefore ye sons of Jacob are not consumed."

Thirdly, Matthew 5:17-18, 17 “Think not that I am come to destroy the Law or the Prophets. I am not come to destroy, but to fulfill.  18 For verily I say unto you, till heaven and earth pass away, not one jot or one tittle shall in any wise pass from the law till all be fulfilled."

And Fourthly, Hebrews 13:8, Jesus Christ is the same yesterday, and today, and for ever."

So, quickly speaking, our Creator does not change, ever, if our Creator changes, we have no security, because we do not know when He will change again, similar to pagan gods like Odin or Zeus, but we see that our Creator does not change.  Nothing about Him changes, character or word.

Sin, described as lawlessness in 1st John, is the absence of obedience to our Creator's ways.  He gave man a way to be pleasing to Him, the observance of His ways.  What are His ways, well, you can start reading about them in the book of Exodus.

Our Creator is always concerned about His people and their observance to His ways (Laws). See this in Ezekial 36:26-27, Hebrews 10:16, and in Revelation 22:14 "Blessed are they that do His commandments, that they may have right to the Tree of Life, and may enter in through the gates into the city."

In thinking about this, here we are, in the last book of the Bible, the last chapter in the last book of the Bible, and our Creator is STILL talking about His commandments!  Do you think our Creator thinks them to be important?

Comment: That's a good answer and not one I would have thought of.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange Rob, thanks for contributing! Be sure to take our [site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about us. [We're a little different from other sites.](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/803/423)

Answer (score 1):

The Greek word here is ἀνομία - *anomia*.  There is actually an English word, "anomie", that is directly derived from the Greek, but it has a fairly loose meaning of "lack of the usual social or ethical standards" (*Concise Oxford English Dictionary*, 6th ed.).

Elsewhere in the ESV (e.g. Hebrews 1:9) it is translated as "wickedness".  The King James translators chose such words as "iniquity" (e.g. Matthew 7:23) and "unrighteousness" (e.g. 2 Corinthians 6:14).  "Iniquity" derives from the Latin *iniquitas*, which was the word used by Latin translators of John for ἀνομία.  Bede (672-735), although commenting in Latin, offers an explanation of the underlying Greek in his commentary on this passage:

> Let no one say, "Sin is one thing, iniquity (*iniquitas*) another." 
>   Let no one say "I am a sinner, but I am not wicked."  *Everyone who
>   commits sin also commits iniquity, and sin is iniquity*.
>
> The force of this thought is grasped more easily in the Greek language
>   in which the Letter is written, since in that language iniquity is
>   called ἀνομία, which implies something done, as it were, against the
>   law or without the law, since in Greek νόμος means law.  When John
>   says therefore, *Everyone who commits sin also commits iniquity*, that
>   is, ἀνομίαν, *and sin is iniquity*, he clearly suggests that by every
>   single sin we act against the law of God, according to the saying of
>   the Psalmist, *I have counted all sinners on earth as transgressors*
>   [Psalm 118:119 LLX].  For all who commit sin are guilty of
>   transgression, that is, not only those who reject the known precepts
>   of the written law which have been given them, but also those who
>   whether through weakness or negligence or even ignorance destroy the
>   innocence of the natural law which we received in the first-created
>   man.
>
> [*Commentary on the Seven Catholic Epistles*](http://amzn.to/2lcs5HN) (tr. Dom David
>   Hurst), pp.187-188

Hence, ἀνομία does not refer to law in the narrow sense of the Mosaic law, but rather the Divine Law that is written on our hearts and minds (Jeremiah 31:33). It refers to our departure from being as befits one who is created in the image and likeness of God.

The Orthodox Christian monk and theologian [Justin Popović](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justin_Popovi%C4%87) (1894-1979) further explains this as follows:

> *Sin* defiles man and his being, which is in the divine image of God and God-given.  It is the fundamental impurity, proto-impurity, and
>   the origin of all impurities.  Purity is, in reality, purity from sin
>   and its impurities.  That is holiness.
>
> For such purity, such holy purity, is the divine law of man's being. 
>   This purity is achieved and maintained by living in goodness in love,
>   in prayer, in righteousness, in meekness, in fasting, in
>   self-restraint, and in the rest of the virtues of the Gospel - simply
>   put, in holiness, conceived of as the synthesis and unity of all the
>   holy virtues and grace-filled energies.  In opposition to purity, to
>   holiness as law, to the divine law of man's being, stands *sin* as the
>   first and fundamental lawlessness.
>
> [*Commentary on the Epistles of St. John the Theologian*,](http://amzn.to/2mt49Ar) p.39